# How can I format a string sheet to date with Query 2

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

I need change

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-11-17T13:41:47.431Z |
| 3 | 2022-11-10T21:42:06-03:00 |
| 3 | 2022-11-10 22:01:00 |

To this with the query on sheets!

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-11-17 13:41:47 |
| 3 | 2022-11-10 21:42:06 |
| 3 | 2022-11-10 22:01:00 |

I tried! Follow the link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X0fbTuorNeIWbusgZ4fWdjzRwxhxUld_iCxqhzJ5uZM/edit#gid=181823931

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this works for you?

```
    = ARRAYFORMULA(
query({A1:A,
    IF(B1:B <> "",
        REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(B1:B), "\d+-\d+-\d+") 
        &" "&
        REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(B1:B), "\d+:\d+:\d+"),
    )}
       ))
```